# Is there a way to install an application from the Safari directly?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for everyone's help
I built a personal application and I do not want to submit it to AppStore.

Is there any way that my friends and family can install the app with a specific link?

Importantly, I do not have a developer account

Without https://www.diawi.com or betafamily.

Can I download an app from my Safari? Like hacked apps?

Comment: Without a developer account !! No you can't.

Comment: with having developer account you can upload your .app file to https://www.diawi.com/ and it will give you link to download your app which will available for some period may 3 days

Comment: No its not possible, Just purchase a developer account and then upload app to TestFlight for Testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the application on your own server and share the link to download the app through browser. But you still need a developer account for the distribution.

You can go through this link http://www.bentedder.com/self-hosting-an-ad-hoc-distribution-ipa-file-for-app-development/ for the process to host your app on your own server.